# Laravel checkboxes with many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

I am pulling diseases from DB and presenting them in front-end with checkboxes:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    @foreach($diseases as $disease)
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>{{ Form::checkbox('diseases','0','',
                                ['class' => 'grey','data-id'=> $disease->id]) }}
                    {{$disease->title}}
                </label>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Once I submit the form, I get the result of the `$request->diseases` like this:

```
1:"1"
2:"1"
3:"0"
4:"1"
5:"0"
6:"0"
...
```

where first number represents `disease_id`, and other one presents whether the checkbox is checked or not. Relationships to the pivot table are made within models correctly, and what I try to do in controller is:

```
if ($request->has('diseases')) {
    $patient->diseases()->sync($request->diseases);
}
```

but this fails with error:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key 
constraint fails (`db_name`.`disease_patient`, CONSTRAINT `disease_patient_patient_id_foreign` 
FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patients` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into 
`disease_patient` (`disease_id`, `patient_id`) 
values (17, {"1":"0","2":"0","3":"1","4":"1","5":"1","6":"1","7":"1","8":"1","9":"0","10":"1","11":"0","12":"1","13":"0","14":"0","15":"0","16":"0","17":"0","18":"0","19":"0","20":"0","21":"0","22":"0","23":"0"}))
```

Relationship inside `Patient` model:

```
protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function diseases()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Disease', 'disease_patient', 'disease_id', 'patient_id');
}
```

**EDIT:**

When I do:

```
$diseases = array_keys(array_filter(json_decode($request->diseases, true)));
return $diseases;
```

I get the list of ID's like so:

```
0:1
1:2
2:8
3:14
4:15
5:21
```

And error:

```
(SQL: insert into `disease_patient` (`disease_id`, `patient_id`) values (33, 1))
```

With `disease_id` incrementing on each request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `sync` method is NOT supposed to be an associative array. You should be passing it a single array containing the disease ID's to attach. To do this, you will need to pre-process your array:

```
if ($request->has('diseases')) {
    $diseases = array_keys(array_filter($request->diseases)));
    $patient->diseases()->sync($diseases);
}
```

If `$request->diseases` returns a Laravel Collection, you may need to call `toArray()` or cast it to an array first.

Reference: The "Syncing Associations" section of https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Comment: Hmm strange, I did a `gettype()` on the request, and I got string? Probably JSON string then. I am trying with `json_decode()`...

Comment: What if you `dd($request);`?

Comment: It is a huuuge list. But if I make that line `$diseases = array_keys(array_filter(json_decode($request->diseases, true)));` I get again integrity violation but now it is being fed with 2 values (27, 1) for `disease_id` and `patient_id`. Second one is ok, first one increments with each request

Comment: Why are you JSON decoding it?

Comment: Because I can't use array methods on string, and `toArray()` doesn't pass as valid. But when I dump the result of that line, I get an array of checked ID's. Maybe something else is wrong? Updated question

Comment: Try swapping disease_id and patient_id in your belongsToMany definition. It looks like it might be trying to use a disease ID where patient ID is.

Comment: Yes! I deleted both the foreign key and local key from relationship in model. Thanks!